# Arguments passed to the services giving dependency non-existence service error in shopware 6

Tags: symfony4, shopware

I have to use `HttpClientInterface` at my service page. So I defined as following:

```
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;


public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }
```

In my `services.xml` file I have also trying passing the argument and also set `autowiring`

```
<!-- SERVICES -->
<service id="SwagMasterBundle\Service\ProductManager" autowire="true" autoconfigure="true">
    <argument id="Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface" type="service" key="$httpClient"></argument>
</service>
```

But I am getting error:

`The service "SwagMasterBundle\Service\ProductManager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface".`

Can anybody help me what I have done wrong here ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect an interface, since an interface needs to be implemented from a concrete class. So, in your case you need an concrete object - Symfony services are simple objects.

Please refer to object orientated programming basics first.

Edit: Also autowiring *and* defining the given services doesn't make sense. Let the framework determine the needed object or do it yourself, but chose one option, not both at a time.

Comment: ok but how can I use httpClient in Shopware 6. I used same way in symfony project.